# How to save list as csv by splitting to columns

Tags: python, csv, machine-learning, dataset, pycharm

I have list of dataset of EEG. They look like this :

```
['-0.9148', '-1.7609', '0.8441', '-3.0872', '-3.3303', '-2.5054', '1.5679', '-4.6378', '-3.5720', '-3.3940']
```

I would like to save them to CSV as

```
['-0.9148', '-1.7609', '0.8441', '-3.0872']
['-3.3303', '-2.5054', '1.5679', '-4.6378']
['-0.9148', '-2.5054', '-3.5720','-3.3940']
```

However, I save them as how it looks like in the list.

Comment: You could make your list a nested list, and then save each sublist as a row.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have already coded without any sublist or nested list. Isn't there any other else way to crack it?

Comment: Related to @thebjorn's answer, you could save slices of the list. `my_list[4:8]` would be your second row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
>>> x = ['-0.9148', '-1.7609', '0.8441', '-3.0872', '-3.3303', '-2.5054', '1.5679', '-4.6378', '-3.5720', '-3.3940']
>>> zip(*[x[i::3] for i in range(4)])
[('-0.9148', '-1.7609', '0.8441', '-3.0872'), ('-3.0872', '-3.3303', '-2.5054', '1.5679'), ('1.5679', '-4.6378', '-3.5720', '-3.3940')]
```

it basically takes the ith element element for as many elements as you need, giving you n vectors of first, second, .. nth elements, then calls zip on the result.

Writing to csv is then:

```
with open('filename.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    w = csv.writer(csvfile)
    w.writerows(zip(*[x[i::3] for i in range(4)]))
```

Comment: Thank you, It really worked and solved my problem. I always love to see clean data in my files. :)

Comment: Glad to help. Upvote (click the up-arrow next to the answer), and accept (click the check mark in the same area) to make it easier for future searchers to find good answers (and give me points ;-)

Comment: Done, even my friends who shared my problem will upvote :))